# Jquery - how to include files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

here is part of html tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
```

and inside custom.js i've got part

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    //$('#mask').hide();    
    //$('#game').hide();
    $('.game-button').hover(
        function() {$(this).fadeTo('fast','1');},
        function() {$(this).fadeTo('slow','0');}
    );
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
      value: 37
     });
    $('#acces a').click(function(){
        $('#mask').fadeIn('fast');
        $('#game').fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

but it doesn't respond. why?

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your HTML markup too?

Comment: nothing shown appears incorrect. Look in browser console for errors thrown and show html

Comment: Looks like your `custom.js` file is not in your current folder because apart from that everything seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `http://` in front of your script sources:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

to be:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

and the same for the jquery-ui library.

Comment: I tried and at least it did not work on firefox. And not working on chrome also. I'm running on windows. But if I add the http my test script works fine.

Comment: `//` is automatically replaced with either `http://` or `https://` depending on whether the requesting website is using http or https. So it's convenient. Unfortunately, it'll be replaced with `file://` if you open your html document from a local folder, and sure enough you can't access JQuery at `file://ajax.googleapis.com...`